# I cannot use @select statement in base/tidier

Tags: julia, dataframes.jl

I'm trying to use select statement but in both examples I'm getting an error message ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: @select not defined. Do you know what may causes that?

```
#DF
names = ["Sally", "Bob", "Alice", "Hank"]
grades = [1, 5, 8.5, 4]
df = DataFrame(; name=names, grades=grades)

#Base
@chain df begin
    @transform(:grades_new = :grades/2)
    @subset(:name .== "Sally")
    @select(:grades)
end

#Tidier
@chain df begin
    @mutate(grades_new = grades/2)
    @filter(name == "Sally")
    @select(grades)
end
```

Comment: Can you add, what packages you loaded? It seems you are `using` `DataFrames`, `Chain`, `Tidier` and `DataFramesMeta`. In which order did you load them?

Comment: I've never installed Chain pkg and haven't used select statement so far, let me check that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a conflict with `DataFramesMeta.@select` and `Tidier.@select`.
Use:

```
using DataFrames, Chain, DataFramesMeta, Tidier

#DF
names = ["Sally", "Bob", "Alice", "Hank"]
grades = [1, 5, 8.5, 4]
df = DataFrame(; name=names, grades=grades)

#DataFramesMeta
@chain df begin
    @transform(:grades_new = :grades/2)
    @subset(:name .== "Sally")
    DataFramesMeta.@select(:grades)
end
#1×1 DataFrame
# Row │ grades  
#     │ Float64 
#─────┼─────────
#   1 │     1.0

#Tidier
@chain df begin
    @mutate(grades_new = grades/2)
    @filter(name == "Sally")
    Tidier.@select(grades)
end
#1×1 DataFrame
# Row │ grades  
#     │ Float64 
#─────┼─────────
#   1 │     1.0
```

In case either `DataFramesMeta` or `Tidier` is used, there is no need to qualify the module. But when they are used together, the module need to be given to know which `@select` will be used.